# How are private variables accessed in operator overloading?

Tags: c++

How can private variables be accessed in operator overloading (obj.real,obj.imag,res.real,res.imag) in this code. Can someone explain

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex {
private:
    int real, imag;
public:
    Complex(int r = 0, int i =0)  {real = r;   imag = i;}

    // This is automatically called when '+' is used with
    // between two Complex objects
    Complex operator + (Complex const &obj) {
         Complex res;
         res.real = real + obj.real;
         res.imag = imag + obj.imag;
         return res;
    }
    void print() { cout << real << " + i" << imag << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4);
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2; // An example call to "operator+"
    c3.print();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: private members of a class are accessible only from within other members of the same class (or from their "friends"). But here real and imag are private variables and obj's real and imag values are accessed from outside the class

Comment: @NiranjanKotha: What are you talking about? No, they're not accessed from outside the class. You defined the operator as a member of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access modifiers(public, private, protected) in C++ apply to the class as a whole, not individual objects. So if a class member is private, it is accessible by any member functions of that class, regardless of which object the member function is being called on.

And this isn't specific to operator overloading. It is applicable to all member functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your operator + should be able to access all private variables, because it's part of the same class. I see no problem here. But if you happened to have functions outside the class, you may use "friend" keyword (often used with streams).
Do you have any errors from compiler?